# Win 7 workstation died. Moved Harddrive to external USB drive and trying to recover to new machine but some profiles are missing

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, user-profiles

I had a Dell workstation running Win 7 32bit.  Motherboard Died.  I pulled the harddrive and put into an external USB drive shell. I can access the drive from the NEW machine but the main user profile is missing in the Local Disk\ Users file. I can access other user profiles but not the main profile.  What am I missing?  Is there a permissions issue?    Help...please!

Comment: How did the machine "die"? It's unusual not to be able to see all the profiles. You may try showing hidden files and folders and failing that running chkdsk on the drive. Its also possible that the profile is named something you wouldn't recognize as the main profile.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.  I found the profiles: Daryl, John and Public but was looking for the profile called "Valerie".   When I viewed the "Daryl" profile I found that the contents were really the "Valerie" profile.  It occurred to me that the computer user was originally "Daryl" but was afterwards renamed/changd to "Valerie" so when looking at the profiles via the windows directory the "Daryl" name remained in effect but really was the new "Valerie" profile.  I have seen this before.